# playn android problems - Netbeans cannot find device

Tags: android, netbeans, playn

As the title states, I'm having troubles running the android version of my playn projects. I found the setup incredibly difficult, but the html and java versions are now running.

I have have eclipse working now, but much prefer netbeans.
Please note that I am able to succesfully deploy *regular* android projects with netbeans.

I have no experience with maven whatsoever, so I'm trying to avoid the command line.

---

**Netbeans**

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/05/24/Using-Netbeans-712-with-PlayN-13.aspx

There are some problems at this point:

> In the Actions list, select Run Project.  Under Execute Goals: enter android:deploy android:run, and under Set Properties: enter skipTests=True and android.device=usb.  Finally click OK.

When I enter all the information, "run" is still greyed out on the android project. When I go back to the actions list, everything is blank again. Seems like the settings are not saved.
However, I can run the project by rightmouse selecting the project -> custom and enter the details there. It's quite annoying to fill everything in each time I want to run the project, but that's a problem to worry about later I guess.

When running the project, it always throws one of these errors:

```
Device not found
Device is offline
ADB not connected
```

When I use adb devices, it lists my device just fine.

Comment: I have just fixed the eclipse problem by chaning xms to 512 and xmx to 1024. The netbeans problem remains, and I would much prefer to use that IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be problem in your Maven setup (add tag to this question). Try to run mentioned targets from command line to see if there is anything specific done by NetBeans IDE.